# Bulk edit Wordpress Post tiltes with mysql or any other way

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a wordpress site with 3000+ posts and the titles have "-" in them like Big-cave-nature-hd-wallpaper-for-Backgrounds". I changed some titles of posts and removed "-" from the the titles but its very time consuming. I want to bulk replace that hyphen "-" from the titles of all the posts replacing it with a space. 
I tried search and replace plugin to replace "-" with a space in titles only but it replaced the "-" with a space in titles of posts as well as urls of the posts and all the posts stopped working.

I want a way so that i can replace "-" with a space in post titles only not the urls or other fields of posts.

Site: http://www.worldofdth.com/home

Any help will be appriciated.
Thanks

Comment: you can do it in your database just by running a single query (as given below by @Donny Bly)

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach to your MySql database using phpMyAdmin or something similar, and issue the following query:

```
update wp_posts set post_title = replace(post_title,'-',' ') where post_status = 'public' and post_type = 'post';
```